# Upload image, reposition it, save image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, drag-and-drop

I am searching for a script where I can upload an image and its displayed inside a container.
Then I can drag the image around as it fits best in this container. After that the image should be saved.
2 hours of searching and nothing found. There are many plugins for cropping but not a single one with just moving or repositioning the uploaded image inside container and a save.

Comment: If your problem is with the image generation part, you'll need to say what you use server-side. If it's PHP have a look at GD: http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery UI Draggables](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement) support the `containment` property, for setting a container in which an element can be dragged.

Upload the image, load it into a div, use that div for `containment`, and then save the position once the user clicks save?

Is there a particular part of this that you're having a problem with?

Comment: yes the problem is im good at frontend stuff... so the drag and drop thing should be easy for me... im having problem to figure out how i should handle the repositioned / moved image that its saved in a folder on my server

Comment: Well you're going to need to post the file and the coordinates to the server. The position of the image is not an inherent property of the image, so that's not something you can simply save to the file system. You have to store them somewhere, such as a database, and then read them back when you're rendering the image. How you do that depends of course on what your serverside environment looks like.